# Select a Row a Table is Grouped by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a table and grouping it by a variable called 'passer_player_name'

```
data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')[['epa']].mean()
passer_index = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')[['epa', 'success','yards_gained']].mean()
passer_index['attempts'] = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')['epa'].count()
```

This gave the following output (a few example lines):

```
                      epa  success  yards_gained  attempts
passer_player_name         
L.Jackson           0.336     0.48           6.9       335
K.Cousins           0.295     0.50           7.1       363
P.Mahomes           0.285     0.50           7.4       368
```

What I am trying to do next required me to grab/sort my table by using the 'passer_player_name' column, however that is technically not part of the table. I tried doing the following:

```
passer_index['passer_names'] = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')['passer_player_name']
```

Unfortunately, this gave the following in the added column (this is one example row):

```
(L.Jackson, [L.Jackson, L.Jackson, L.Jackson, ...
```

How would I get a column that simply says the player's name once, like a column that would just have the output 'L.Jackson' (obviously different for each player's name)?

Comment: `passer_index.index`

Comment: please show your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I found to my own question.

The line that gets the data that I a looking for is the following:

```
passer_index['passer_names'] = passer_index.index.values
```

Basically just putting the name of your array + '.index.values'. A more generic example to get this is the following (with 'df' being the dataframe's variable name):

```
df.index.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried incorporating:

```
df.sort_index()
```

When your format is the way you have it, you can sort by that